# Clustered cache in Jboss 3.2.6 version

Tags: caching, cluster-computing, jboss-3.x

I have a requirement of clustered cache in JBoss version 3.2.6.

Is Clustered cache possible in Jboss 3.2.6 version or not?

And if yes than please provide any references since I have looked up for it but I got of JBoss 5 or higher versions.

Answer (score 0):

I never use JBoss 3 but in the documentation you can find some information about clustering - probably  you can use that version in cluster.

More info you can find on these sites:

- [JBoss Application Server Official Documentation Page](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossApplicationServerOfficialDocumentationPage)
- [JBoss 3.2.6 - JBoss Admin Development Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/admindevel326/html/)

Answer (score 0):

First off, JBossAS v3 is *seriously* old (3.2.6 was released in [October 2004](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/)). You're running a huge risk by continuing to use it, since you'll get absolutely no meaningful support from RedHat (or anyone else).

Having said that, it does contain a very early version of JBossCache, which probably has some basic support for replicated (i.e. "clustered") caches. There's very little documentation from back then, but it will resemble the standalone version of JBossCache that later became v1.4.  See the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosscache/1.4.0/TreeCache/en/html_single/index.html) to see where to start looking.